# Binding to a datatemplate control WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a TabControl which binds an `ObservableCollecion<T>`. Every tab represents one object from OC. In the tab header i have a button:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}">x</Button>
```

which should delete an object from the observable collection and consequently represent the result as the deleted tab. However the command is not acknowledged when i click on the x button, probably because it searches for a property in its model(?). Is there any way this would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind to TabControl's `DataContext` using `RelativeSource` markup extension.

Also, in case you want to remove the item from ObservableCollection, pass the binding via `CommandParameter` which will be an instance of T (model object).

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.TestCommand, 
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                   AncestorType=TabControl}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```